# how to hide or show calculated member within a role in ssas cube

Tags: ssas, role

Let's say I have a Country.Country attribute in my cube. The members are:
  ARGENTINA
  AUSTRALIA
  BRAZIL
  CANADA
  JAPAN
  INDIA
  BANGLADESH
  NEPAL

I want to create two roles:

Role1 will have access to ARGENTINA, AUSTRALIA and JAPAN only
Role2 will have ARGENTINA, AUSTRALIA, BRAZIL, CANADA and ASIA.

Here ASIA is aggregated value of JAPAN, INDIA, BANGLADESH and NEPAL.

To have ASIA, I wrote:

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Country].[Country].[All].[AISA] 
as 
aggregate({[Country].[Country].&[JAPAN],[Country].[Country].&[INDIA], 
           [Country].[Country].&[BANGLADESH], [Country].[Country].&[NEPAL]});

Now I am facing two problems:

1. As it is a calculated member under country then it will show to both roles. But I don't want it in Role1.
2. In Role2, I  want ASIA instead of JAPAN, INDIA, BANGLADESH and NEPAL. So i have to make these countries hidden by un-checking. Then if I uncheck them then the value of ASIA will be "#VALUE!" as it won't find those countries that are needed to form ASIA.

Is there any way to achieve this requirement?